# EntityFramework DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity accepts and saves data instead of generating new one

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Assuming this test model:

```
public class TestEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate a new instance of it, `Id` is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

Saving such an instance in the database **as a new row**, results in a Guid being generated (which is different from the empty one).

However, if I provide a valid Guid in `TestEntity.Id`, the new row is created with the provided Guid instead of a newly computed one.

I would like this behavior to exists only when editing a row, not when creating it. This is to ensure a database-layer protection from attacks where a user normally shouldn't get to choose which data to input.

Off course this protection is present in other layers, but I want it in the database too. Is this possible? How can I tell EF to ignore model data when creating a new row?

`DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` descriptions says

> the database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated

So clearely that's not an option. I don't want to change Id when updating a row. I only want to be sure no one can create a row and choose the Id.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to keep things simple. Make your `set` method protected, then you have two ways to generate `Ids`, You can generate it by yourself inside a constructor:

```
public class TestEntity
{
    // no need to decorate with `DatabasGenerated`, since it won't be generated by database...
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TestEntity()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

...or you can let the database generate it for you. At least for SQL Server, it will be able to generate for `int` and `Guid` as well:

```
public class TestEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // no need to generate a Guid by yourself....

}
```

This will avoid people from setting a value to `Id` outside the class (therefore no one can choose a Guid for new rows, or modify from existing ones).
Of course, your team could use reflection to by-pass class definitions, but if that's the case, you need to have a talk with your team.

If you still want to make sure they won't *cheat*, then you'd have to do check before saving changes to database, maybe overriding `SaveChanges()` in your `DbContext`.

> As a side note, for both `int` and `Guid`, values are not generated by Entity Framework. Decorating the property with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` will tell Entity Framework to generate a column with a default value coming from the own database provider.

Comment: Only problem with this solution is the class constructor as I'd like EF to be generating the id. For the Guid, it's ok... but if I were using an incremental Integer as id, that would no longer be ok. Also, my concern is not coders cheating with reflections but merely myself and users: if I forget to unbind a property from the UI, then the user can attack in the way described. "Protected set" seems like a perfect solution, as long as EF is still able to set it: I'll test it out and accept if it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Saturnix I edited my answer to provide more details, now that I understand your concerns. If you use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, you don't need to use a constructor to generate the `Id` (no matter is `int` or `Guid`), because the own database (at least SQL Server) will generate it. Also, EF is able to set protected properties with no problems.